# How to decrease clipping in emitter follower

Tags: amplifier, class-a

I have a small headphone amplifier with an class A output stage and some negative feedback. The result is not good, but the point is purely self-educational. The part are all jelly-beans and certainly not optimised for audio.

My test circuit can be simplified to this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fahRoQ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

\$V_{in}\$ has a maximum peak value of \$1.5\text{V}\$. One issue is certainly that the op-amp can't go close enough to its positive supply rail to compensate the \$V_{be}\$ drop, but that's not the one I'm interested in now.

The second issue is that the emitter can't go below \$-2.5\frac{R_L}{R_L+R_e}\$ without \$I_e\$ going to zero and thus reverse-biaising the base-emitter junction. It will mean that close to that negative voltage, there will be distortion (due to varying \$V_{be}\$ drop) and clipping below that value.

One solution would be to decrease \$R_e\$, but that would mean bigger losses. I know class A isn't supposed to be very efficient, but if I decrease \$R_L\$ to more common headphone impedance values, I would have to decrease \$R_e\$ even more and lose tons of power.

I could of course use a class B or AB instead, but, just for the sake of my own education, would there be another way?

Comment: You're stuck with the laws of physics/electronics here.  That's why class B/AB and especially class D were invented.

Comment: huh? emitter followers aren't in saturation.

Comment: That +/- 2.5V DC supply is a severe limitation. You might as well just drive headphones directly from the opamp. A headphone might produce 100 dB (SPL) driven by 1 mW. The opamp's internal current-limiter may save your ears.

Comment: @user_1818839 I should have said "clipping", saturation is maybe a mistranslation from French, sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That type of output stage has a maximum efficiency of ~12-15%.

You can increase the efficiency a bit by biasing it asymmetrically with a larger negative than positive supply.

You can increase efficiency further by using a current source instead of the emitter resistor.
[image]

https://www.edn.com/distortion-in-power-amplifiers-part-viii-class-a-amplifiers/

Comment: It seems to be the answer I was looking for. Thank you. I really should read Douglas Self's books some day

Comment: @JonasDaverio - I definitely recommend Douglas Self's books. I was looking for another article I had seen on the emitter follower output stages but so far have not found it.